# JPEG image generator. How to stamp W x H dimensions on image?

Tags: typescript, jpeg, deno

I've been looking for a piece of Deno/TypeScript code that generates simple images with dimensions on them. I've put together the code below as an example. It generates images in JPEG, base64 & dataURL.

As you can see, it pushes RGB pixels one by one into a Number Array in order to construct the image.

```
// Import jpeg encoder
import { encode as pixelsToBin } from "https://deno.land/x/jpegts@1.1/mod.ts";
// Import std base64 encoder
import { encode as binTob64 } from "https://deno.land/std/encoding/base64.ts";

// Make A jpeg Image with RED, GREEN, BLUE & ALPHA colors

/***
 * 
 * Material Desing Colors | Range 500
 * 
 * 19 colors
 * 
 * RED ---------> #f44336 -> rgba(244,  67,  54, 1)
 * PINK --------> #e91e63 -> rgba(233,  30,  99, 1)
 * PURPLE ------> #9c27b0 -> rgba(156,  39, 176, 1)
 * DEEP-PURPLE -> #673ab7 -> rgba(103,  58, 183, 1)
 * INDIGO ------> #3f51b5 -> rgba( 63,  81, 181, 1)
 * BLUE --------> #2196f3 -> rgba( 63,  81, 181, 1)
 * LIGHT-BLUE --> #03a9f4 -> rgba(  3, 169, 244, 1)
 * CYAN --------> #00bcd4 -> rgba(  0, 188, 212, 1)
 * TEAL --------> #009688 -> rgba(  0, 150, 136, 1)
 * GREEN -------> #4caf50 -> rgba( 76, 175,  80, 1)
 * LIGHT-GREEN -> #8bc34a -> rgba(139, 195,  74, 1)
 * LIME --------> #cddc39 -> rgba(205, 220,  57, 1)
 * YELLOW ------> #ffeb3b -> rgba(255, 235,  59, 1)
 * AMBER -------> #ffc107 -> rgba(255, 193,   7, 1)
 * ORANGE ------> #ff9800 -> rgba(255, 152,   0, 1)
 * DEEP-ORANGE -> #ff5722 -> rgba(255,  87,  34, 1)
 * BROWN -------> #795548 -> rgba(121,  85,  72, 1)
 * GREY --------> #9e9e9e -> rgba(158, 158, 158, 1)
 * BLUE-GREY ---> #607d8b -> rgba( 96, 125, 139, 1)
 * 
 */

// Convert HEX color to RGB color
function hexToRgb(cHex): Array<number> {
  const r = parseInt(cHex.slice(1, 3), 16);
  const g = parseInt(cHex.slice(3, 5), 16);
  const b = parseInt(cHex.slice(5, 7), 16);
  // return {r, g, b} // return an object
  return [ r, g, b ];
}

async function saveJpeg(w: number, h: number, cHex: string, fileName: string) {

  // The jpeg image dimensions
  const jpegWidth:  number = w;
  const jpegHeight: number = h;
  const jpegArea:   number = (jpegWidth * jpegHeight);

  // Set jpegPixelColor RGB color based on input HEX color
  const jpegPixelColor: number[] = hexToRgb(cHex);

  // The jpegPixels array
  let jpegPixels: number[] = [];

  for(let i=0; i < jpegArea; i++) {

    // Push a COLOR pixel into jpegPixels array
    jpegPixels.push(jpegPixelColor[0]);
    jpegPixels.push(jpegPixelColor[1]);
    jpegPixels.push(jpegPixelColor[2]);
    jpegPixels.push(1); // alpha - ignored in JPEGs

  }

  // The image layout & data
  const jpegImage: Image = {
    width: jpegWidth,
    height: jpegHeight,
    data: new Uint8Array(jpegPixels)
  }

  // Encode image layout & data to jpeg
  const jpegRaw: Image = pixelsToBin(jpegImage, 100); //Quality 100 (default is 50)

  // Save red-500.jpg binary image to the file system
  await Deno.writeFile(`${fileName}.jpg`, jpegRaw.data);

  // Save red-500.txt base64 image to the file system
  // await Deno.writeTextFile('red-base64.txt', binTob64(jpegRaw.data));

  // Save red-500.txt base64 image data url to the file system
  // await Deno.writeTextFile('red-base64-url.txt', `data:image/jpeg;base64,${binTob64(jpegRaw.data)}`);

}

// Save the jpeg file with dimensions, hex color & file name
await saveJpeg(640, 360, "#f44336", "red-500");

// Save the jpeg file with dimensions, hex color & file name
await saveJpeg(640, 360, "#4caf50", "green-500");

// Save the jpeg file with dimensions, hex color & file name
await saveJpeg(640, 360, "#2196f3", "blue-500");
```

Looking at what this simple library is capable of, how would I go about stamping the image dimensions on the image itself?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. After some research I was able to use a different library to achieve this task.

Here are the results:

```
// Import Canvas API for Deno, ported from canvaskit-wasm (Skia)
import { createCanvas } from "https://deno.land/x/canvas/mod.ts";
// Import std base64 encoder
import { encode as binTob64 } from "https://deno.land/std/encoding/base64.ts";

// Make a PNG Image in Deno with teh Canvas API

/***
 * 
 * Material Desing Colors
 * 
 * 19 background colors in the 500 range
 * 
 * RED ---------> #f44336 -> rgba(244,  67,  54, 1)
 * PINK --------> #e91e63 -> rgba(233,  30,  99, 1)
 * PURPLE ------> #9c27b0 -> rgba(156,  39, 176, 1)
 * DEEP-PURPLE -> #673ab7 -> rgba(103,  58, 183, 1)
 * INDIGO ------> #3f51b5 -> rgba( 63,  81, 181, 1)
 * BLUE --------> #2196f3 -> rgba( 63,  81, 181, 1)
 * LIGHT-BLUE --> #03a9f4 -> rgba(  3, 169, 244, 1)
 * CYAN --------> #00bcd4 -> rgba(  0, 188, 212, 1)
 * TEAL --------> #009688 -> rgba(  0, 150, 136, 1)
 * GREEN -------> #4caf50 -> rgba( 76, 175,  80, 1)
 * LIGHT-GREEN -> #8bc34a -> rgba(139, 195,  74, 1)
 * LIME --------> #cddc39 -> rgba(205, 220,  57, 1)
 * YELLOW ------> #ffeb3b -> rgba(255, 235,  59, 1)
 * AMBER -------> #ffc107 -> rgba(255, 193,   7, 1)
 * ORANGE ------> #ff9800 -> rgba(255, 152,   0, 1)
 * DEEP-ORANGE -> #ff5722 -> rgba(255,  87,  34, 1)
 * BROWN -------> #795548 -> rgba(121,  85,  72, 1)
 * GREY --------> #9e9e9e -> rgba(158, 158, 158, 1)
 * BLUE-GREY ---> #607d8b -> rgba( 96, 125, 139, 1)
 * 
 */

async function savePNG(w: number, h: number, bgHex: string, fgHex: string, fileName: string) {

  const pngWidth: number = w;
  const pngHeight: number = h;

  const canvas = createCanvas(pngWidth, pngHeight);

  const canvasCenter: any = {
    x: Math.floor(canvas.width / 2),
    y: Math.floor(canvas.height / 2),
  };

  const context2d = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context2d.fillStyle = bgHex;
  context2d.fillRect(0, 0, pngWidth, pngHeight); // X, Y, W, H

  // Some font size: 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72
  const fontSize: number = Math.floor(pngHeight * 0.125); // Set to a % of pngHeight

  // console.log("fontSize:", fontSize);

  context2d.fillStyle = fgHex;
  context2d.font = `${fontSize}px sans-serif`;

  // The text to display
  const text: string = `${pngWidth}x${pngHeight}`;

  // Measure the width of a single character
  const charWidth: number = Math.floor(context2d.measureText("X").width);
  // Get length of the text string
  const textLength: number = text.length;
  // Get textWidth for selected fontSize
  const textWidth: number = charWidth * textLength;

  // console.log("textWidth:", textWidth);

  // Get textHeight - Same as fontSize
  const textHeight: number = parseInt(context2d.font);

  // console.log("textHeight:", textHeight);

  // Generate text at center x, y of image
  context2d.fillText(text, Math.floor(canvasCenter.x - (textWidth / 2)), Math.floor(canvasCenter.y + (textHeight / 2))); // X, Y position

  // Save image.png to the file system
  await Deno.writeFile(`${fileName}.png`, canvas.toBuffer());

  // Save image.png in base64 format to the file system
  // await Deno.writeTextFile('image-base64.txt', binTob64(canvas.toBuffer()));

  // Save image.png as data URL png in base64 format to the file system
  // await Deno.writeTextFile('image-base64-url.txt', `data:image/png;base64,${binTob64(canvas.toBuffer())}`);

}

// Save the jpeg file with dimensions, colors & file name
await savePNG(1000, 1000, "#f44336", "#ffcdd2", "red-500");

// Save the jpeg file with dimensions, colors & file name
await savePNG(750, 750, "#4caf50", "#c8e6c9", "green-500");

// Save the jpeg file with dimensions, colors & file name
await savePNG(50, 50, "#2196f3", "#bbdefb", "blue-500");
```